# Elementary properties of the "forgetful" functor from simplicial sets to semisimplicial sets?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Would anyone know a reference which explains whether the forgetful/restriction functor from simplicial to semisimplicial sets is, or fails to be: full, faithful, essentially surjective, etc?